# Estou com problemas em inserir dados em PDO

Tags: php, pdo, inserir

Já verifiquei esse código varias vezes e não achei o erro, por favor me ajudem achar e corrigir...

```
echo"email = ".$email. "<br>" ;
echo "ddd = ".$ddd ."<br>";
echo "telefone = ".$telefone . "<br>";
echo "cpf = ".$cpf . "<br>";
echo "produto = ".$produto . "<br>" ;
echo "status = ".$status . "<br>" ;
echo "total = ".$total . "<br>" ;
echo "data = ".$data . "<br>";
echo "ref = ".$ref. "<br>";


$inseri= $pdo -> prepare (" INSERT INTO " .rico_vendas. "(id, email, ddd, telefone, cpf, produto, status, valor, data_cadastrado, ref) 
VALUES (:id, :email, :ddd, :tel, :cpf, :produto, :status, :valor, :data, :ref)");

 try{
$inseri= $pdo -> prepare ($sql);
$inseri -> bindValue(':id',NULL); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':email',$email); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':ddd',$ddd); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':tel',$telefone); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':cpf',$cpf); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':produto',$produto); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':status',$status); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':valor',$total); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':data',$data); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':ref',$ref); 
$executa = $inseri -> execute();

if($executa){
           echo 'Dados inseridos com sucesso';
       }
       else{
           echo 'Erro ao inserir os dados - '. print_r($pdo->errorInfo());;
       }
   }
   catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54243/discussion-on-question-by-lucas-vinicius-estou-com-problemas-em-inserir-dados-em)

Answer (score 0):

Teu código está estranho amigo!
Tem "prepare" em lugares estranhos e está a faltar a variável $sql.
Geralmente a gente faz isso ai em baixo:
Veja se dá certo assim:

```
<?php
try {
$pdo = new PDO(DSN,DBUSER,DBUSERPASSWD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Falha ao se conectar ao Banco de Dados: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n"; die();
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO rico_vendas (id, email, ddd, telefone, cpf, produto, status, valor, data_cadastrado, ref) 
VALUES (:id, :email, :ddd, :tel, :cpf, :produto, :status, :valor, :data, :ref)";
$inseri = $pdo->prepare("$sql");
$inseri -> bindValue(':id',NULL); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':email',$email); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':ddd',$ddd); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':tel',$telefone); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':cpf',$cpf); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':produto',$produto); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':status',$status); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':valor',$total); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':data',$data); 
$inseri -> bindValue(':ref',$ref); 
$inseri->execute();
$count = $inseri->rowCount();
if($inseri->rowCount() > 0){ echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso!";
    } else { echo "Erro ao inserir os dados!";}
?>
```

Abraço garoto!
Sucesso e muito aprendizado na arte da programação!